# Can I set a default value for a path variable at RequestMapping in SpringMVC?

Tags: spring-mvc

Is it possibile to set a default value to a @PathVariable in SpringMVC?

```
 @RequestMapping(value = {"/core/organization/{pageNumber}", "/core/organization"} , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list(@PathVariable Integer pageNumber, ModelMap modelMap) {
```

In this case. If I access the page without pageNumber I want to set a default value to 1.

Is that possible?

Comment: I doubt it, as you can't have default values for method params in java

Comment: No you cannot have a default for a path variable as without the variable the URL would be different and thus not match. You can always create a mapping for `/core/organization` which internally calls the `list` method with the default value you want.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to to set a default value, but you can create two methods:

```html
@RequestMapping(value = {"/core/organization/{pageNumber}", "/core/organization"} , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list(@PathVariable Integer pageNumber, ModelMap modelMap){
...
}


@RequestMapping(value = {"/core/organization/", "/core/organization"} , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list(@PathVariable Integer pageNumber, ModelMap modelMap){
Integer pageNumber=defaultvalue;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but if you want a default showing up in swagger, you can use `@ApiImplicitParams`/`@ApiImplicitParam` to annotate the function, with a `defaultValue` and `paramType="path"` specified.